# intermittent ClassNotFoundException for JSP using eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

Running Eclipse Indigo, Tomcat 7 on Windows - running the web application on the ROOT context with eclipse wtp plugin I am getting this intermittent problem where eclipse cannot find the compiled JSP. It occurs when first accessing the JSP and cannot be resolved except by stopping  the Tomcat server and cleaning the Work directory and the project directory. The compile version is there in the eclipse directory structure:

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\...
```

but it still produces this error.

After some research I found this related thread which seems to suggest the problem only occurs when the application is deployed on ROOT.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.tomcat.user/208071

And a bug has been entered:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334977

Has anyone had a similar issue to this and knows a solution?

Comment: I have this problem as well, but with Tomcat 6 on a Mac.

Comment: Same problem here, anybody got a solution yet?

Comment: I had this issue earlier with Eclipse Galileo and Tomcat, the fact that it is *intermittent* is the problem

Comment: me too...I don't have to clean anything...just stop and restart.  A **real** PITA.  Here's the exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.mortgageReferrals_jsp

Comment: Ah, indeed, I am also seeing this since I switched WTP to use root. Thanks for that bug report!

Comment: Seeing the same error. In run mode I can stop/clean/restart the server but it consistently fails in debug mode no matter what I do. Thanks for the bug report - anyone have any work arounds besides stop/clean/restart?

Comment: Same issue, debugging it showed that the JasperLoader classLoader lost reference to some of the necessary work URLs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27297386/822870 where it recommends to delete the tmp0 folder. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try to configure value as per first screen shot and change location as per second screenshot and try if that works for you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that it works, as it is an intermittent problem; however, since I switched this setting, I have not seen the problem resurface. If I see it, I'll come back here, drop my up-vote, and comment that it did not fix it.

Comment: Well, turns out it didn't stick. I just got another instance of this problem, even with this in place...It won't let me downgrade my vote, so consider the votes on this to be -1