# Eclipse Indigo / WTP - compiled JSP not found

Tags: tomcat7, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-wtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [intermittent ClassNotFoundException for JSP using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953456/intermittent-classnotfoundexception-for-jsp-using-eclipse)

I have a dynamic web project that uses Jersey to return Viewable JSPs.  I start up my server (tomcat 7 / java 1.6), and go hit my URL and see the error below.  I know there's nothing wrong with the code because if I kill the server and restart it, everything works fine.  My app is deployed with a context root of "/" and I need it to stay that way.  This is *killing* my productivity.....anybody else seeing this error with eclipse/WTP?

> javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.sales.annualAllocation_jsp
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:910)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:858)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:812)
>       com.purduefed.filters.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:47)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>       org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:62)
>       org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:196)
>       org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:93)

Comment: a stab in the dark:  is your installed JRE from a JDK installation.  If not try that...

Comment: [There is a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334977) related to running in the root context (like `http://localhost:8080` rather than `http://localhost:8080/some-path`). Too bad you're saying your application needs that.

Comment: I'll give my app a context root and see if it "solves" the issue....